# Signal parameters compatibility between DragonFly 1.5 & old amplifier

Tags: amplifier

I have DragonFly 1.5 Black (spec: http://www.audioquest.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/dragonfly-spec-sheet-darktheme.pdf). I'd like to connect it (via minijack - 2xcinch cable) to the very old amplifier Denon PMA-960 (spec: http://audio-database.com/DENON-COLUMBIA/amp/pma-960-e.html).

Could you please tell me (because I don't have enough technical knowledge) if the signal parameters of Dragonfly's (1.2 V or 2.1 V - depends on version) output minijack (in whole volume range) are within the tolerance range for the AUX (line-in) connector of the amplifier and "line-level" specification?

I don't want cause damage devices.

Can I also connect notebook (Dell E5450) to this amplifier?

I will be very grateful for your response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2V is no problem for AUX In,  as audio IC's readily accept input up to their supply voltage (which is much greater than this),  and many beyond the rails, without damage.  AUX normally expects 1V with a wide range.